# How to fix 2007 Dodge Ram Hemi Overdrive Problem

Tags: dodge, gears, ram

When my friend is going at least 70 MPH the overdrive doesn't work.

And sometimes the overdrive doesn't work when he's going 40 MPH!

What could I do to fix the problem.

And I would like to avoid going to a repair shop.

Comment: Is this an intermittent thing? Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't? Or it never works?

Comment: It doesn't work when we're going 70 MPH, most of the time the overdrive works @ 40 MPH, @Paulster2

Comment: How do you know the OD isn't working when it isn't then? Do the RPM's of the truck go up substantially and not come back down? Or what?

Comment: The RPMs just keep jumping, @Paulster2

Comment: Are you sure the transmission isn't just slipping?

Comment: It's not that! My friend put new oil about a month ago, @Paulster2

Comment: The only way you are going to know is to have it taken to a shop. We are just guessing here. No way to diagnose this over the internet. The question just has too many answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overdrive is misunderstood.

The traditional definition is:

a gear that drives the rear rotations to be lower than that of the crankshaft.

That means you truck shouldn't go into 'overdrive' at 40mph.  No car does this.  At a higher speed, in order to conserve fuel, a car may go into overdrive.

Knowing if your vehicle is actually going into overdrive, or not, is not a no brainer.  Making a claim of, 'it doesn't go into overdrive' doesn't mean it isn't, it only means you believe it isn't.  Two different things.

What are the facts regarding your vehicle "not going into overdrive".  If you explain that claim then someone here can help you to resolve why it isn't functioning properly.